# Magento2 Dynamic Rows not providing position with data array

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

I have created a dynamicRows component for Customer Edit Form.
For some reason, if I set visible to false on the field "position", when I submit a new record, the position is never part of the data array.

```
<field name="position">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item -->
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Position</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">position</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
```

When the field is visible, then the key "position" is provided and everything works perfect, but I prefer this field to stay hidden. 
This only happens when adding a new row.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

i just have the same issue, in the magento documentation if we set visible to false, it should apply a css class to display none, but it's not the case.
What i did is use and hidden input. Like that :

```
<field name="position" formElement="hidden">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">option.order</item>
                  <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
              </item>
     </argument>
</field>
```

But the problem now is that the `thead` is still displayed and render the table quite ugly.
So in your component you can use your own template :

`<dynamicRows name="slide" template="MyNamespace_MyModule/dynamic-rows/templates/default">`

And then in your custom template just change the condition to display the `thead`.

Hope it helps ! :)